# Probability of picking a ball from urn when ball is in general more likely to be picked than others.

Tags: probability

The probability of picking a *particular* ball from an urn of $n$ balls (without replacement), on the $x$th try is $P(x,n) = \frac 1 {n}$.  (e.g. If you pick on the first try it is $\frac 1{n}$, on the second try it's $ \frac {n-1}{n} \frac 1{n-1} = \frac 1{n}$ and so on... )

However if this particular ball is more likely to be picked than all the others, then $P(x,n)$ must be greater for lower $x$, and therefore no longer uniform.

If the target ball is always 2 times more likely to be picked than a standard ball, what is $P(x,n)$, and more generally if the target ball is always $r$ times more likely to be picked, what is $P(x,n,r)$ ?

If $r \in \{\mathbb{Z} > 0\} $, I have managed to get:

$ P(x,n,r) = \frac {r(n-1)!(n-x+r-1)!} {(n-x)!(n+r+1)!} $

By the product, of the preceding misses:

$\prod_{i=n-x-1}^{n-1} \frac{i}{i + r}$

And the final hit:

$\frac{r}{n-x+r}$

But I am interested in a simplified solution for $r \in \{\mathbb{R} > 0\}$

I think this might involve gamma function?

Comment: This is not clear.  How can $P(x,n)$ be independent of $x$?

Comment: If you pick it on the first try, its 1/n, if on the second its n-1 / n x 1/(n-1) and so on, so its uniform discrete distribution. I'll try to make that more clear

Comment: I've reworded it, sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Do you mean the probability of getting it on the $x^{th}$ try for the first time?  Are you drawing without replacement?  Then of course $P(x,n)=0$ for $x>n$.  But for $x≤n$ I agree (assuming you meant "without replacement").

Comment: Sorry that is what I mean, I have a very weak maths background so I don't have the conceptual knowledge to state it clearly!  If you would edit the question, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: There's a recursion.  The probability that you get the preferred ball on the first try is $\frac r{r+(n-1)}$ so the probability that you get a different one is $\frac {n-1}{r+(n-1)}$ and then you are in the same situation with $n-1$ balls.  Thus $P(x,n,r)=P(x-1,n-1,r)\times \frac {n-1}{r+(n-1)}$.

Comment: @james_alvarez, You don't seem to be using that $r$ is an integer, except that you write things with factorials. Instead, if you write the factorials as products, is there any reason it wouldn't work with $r$ any nonnegative real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are $m$ balls that you want to pick and $n$ balls in total. The probability of picking a ball of interest on the first try is $P(x=1, n, m)=m/n$, for the second try $P(x=2, n, m)=(1-P(x=1,n,m))\cdot P(x=1, n-1, m)$ and so on. The general case is

$$P(x, n, m)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{x} (1-P(1, n-i, m))\right) \cdot P(1, n-(x-1), m)$$

I don't see a reason why you cannot consider $m\in \mathbb{R}$ in the above formula, so the above formula should do it.

Trying to recover your results with the above mentioned formula I get

$$P(x, n, m) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{x} \frac{n-i-m}{n-i}\right) \cdot \frac{m}{n-(x-1)}$$

Comment: That seems corrrect, I was originally looking for a formula without product notation - but not really necessary for my purpose. Thanks.